# Retrieve ID2D1DeviceContext from IDirect3DDevice9

Tags: c++, directx-9, ms-media-foundation

I am using Source Reader to read video samples from a video file, and decode them using decoder then I am rendering these samples using DirectX9.

I am using `IDirect3DDevice9` for rendering video frames, and it is working as expected.

Now I want to add in Chroma-key Effect, a described in below like:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn890715(v=vs.85).aspx

So how do I get `ID2D1DeviceContext` from `IDirect3DDevice9` and then add Chorma-key effect to it and then render the video frame?

Comment: Chromay key can be done using shader directly on the IDirect3DDevice9. If you are intersting, i've already done it with good results.

Answer (score 4):

ID2D1DeviceContext requires DirectX11 device and can not be used with obsolete IDirect3DDevice9. Typically you create objects in the following order: DXGI Factory, D2D1 Factory, D3D11 Device, DXGI Device, D2D1 Device and then finally D2D1 Device Context. You may want to check [D2D getting starting guide and samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh780340(v=vs.85).aspx).

There is no real point in dealing with DirectX9 anymore, unless you are forced to provide backward compatibility for Windows XP. Chroma-key sample you posted requires Windows 10.

Comment: So you mean I need to use DirectX11 and not DirectX9. Currently I have created sample code which uses DirectX9 API to render video frames. So I will need to replace this code with DirectX11 APIs. Is there any sample code which can read samples from video file and then display them using DirectX11 APIs? Basically I want to apply chroma-key effect to a video stream using provided sample.

Comment: Yes, you need to use DirectX11 (or DirectX10) api. Convert your code to store frame in ID3D11Texture2D then extract IDXGISurface from it, then ID2D1Bitmap1 from DXGI surface and then use this D2D bitmap as render target of you D2D drawing / filters. Some sample code could be found at the page I've posted earlier.

Answer (score 0):

> So how do I get `ID2D1DeviceContext` from `IDirect3DDevice9`...

You cannot get one from the other. The interfaces belong to different APIs, if you use Media Foundation with Direct3D 9 for decoding, Direct2D (where `ID2D1DeviceContext` belongs to) is just nowhere used there.

The closest to your request is use of interoperability between the APIs. See [Direct2D and Direct3D Interoperability Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-and-direct3d-interoperation-overview) for introduction and note the Direct3D versions mentioned there.

See also: [Surface Sharing Between Windows Graphics APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/surface-sharing-between-windows-graphics-apis). The picture below shows that newer APIs interoperate via DXGI, not as old as Direct3D 9 though. Also see comments below for a fresher MSDN link.

[image]
<sub>(source: [s-msft.com](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC534123.png))</sub>

Comment: I need to add Chroma-Key effect on the video frames that are read using source reader. And I found this APIs provided by the MS for Chroma-Key so I was trying to get `ID2D1DeviceContext`. So if I need to use APIs proved by MS for Chroma-Key what approach I will need to follow.

Comment: @Roman R. Note that the image you posted is somewhat obsolete. D2D can work with DX11 just fine (but not with DX12 yet). DXGI evolved to version 1.5 and so on...

Comment: Also [MS Media Foundation can be used with DirectX11 just fine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162912(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @VTT: You are correct, in the same time I think the image gives the right idea that APIs do interoperate (green arrows between D2D and D3D11 through DXGI are anyway shown, even though indirectly). So it's workable with D3D11, but not (or not equally easy) with D3D9 as OP asked. Also, it's not just MSDN reference, I myself used D3D11+MF so it's known to be working as documented.